# Mapping nested data of an array objects in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new and still exploring displaying and mapping data in React JS.

I want to display the nested data array objects but it behave that I wanted.
Here is the data:

[Data json payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs95I.png)

```
{
name: {},
tld: [],
subregion: "Western Europe",
languages: {
   fra: "French",
   gsw: "Swiss German",
   ita: "Italian",
   roh: "Romansh"
},
```

I want to display also the language object data but it always returns an error.

Here is the code blocks on how I tried to observe the behavior of the data:

```
console.log(countries)
    countries.map(country => {
        console.log('Name:', country.name.common)
        console.log('Area:', country.area),
        console.log('Language:', country.languages)
        // Object.keys(country.languages).map((language) => {
        //  console.log(language)
        // })
    });
```

I tried using Object.keys but it also returns an error
ShowCountry.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

I also tried using .map()

```
{countries.map(country => (
            <div>
                <p>Country: {country.name.common}</p>
                <p>Area: {country.area}</p>
                <h3>Languages</h3>
                <ul>
                {/* {country.languages.map((language) => (
                    <li>{language}</li>
                    ))ther 
                } */}
                </ul>
            </div>
          ))
          }
```

It returns an error that country.languages.map is not a function and I suspect maybe its null or empty. This method is what I usually see in the Stackoverflow questions and It should supposed to work but I noticed that the language is an object language: {...} while the other questions are array objects such as array: [{...}, {...}].

I think the problem is easy but I cant figure out the problem. Can you help me out and also give a little bit of explanation or related links about this.

Comment: Add the json payload to your question and not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image you've provided and your question, as far as I'm concerned, it appears that you're trying to represent an object as an array.
you can use `Object.keys()`

And to address the error `ShowCountry.jsx:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`, You will add the check `country.languages &&` to construct the code as follows.

```js
{countries.map((country) => (
  <div key={country.name.common}>
    <p>Country: {country.name.common}</p>
    <p>Area: {country.area}</p>
    {country.languages && (
      <div>
        <h3>Languages</h3>
        <ul>
          {Object.keys(country.languages).map((key) => (
            <li key={key}>{country.languages[key]}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Wow this works, thanks a lot. I am going to dig deeper about Objects.keys methods.

Comment: One thing I've also noticed that there should be an {country.languages &&} to render nothing if the data is not yet prepared but if the data is ready, then render the objects.key. I wonder if mapping it(.map()) instead of using the the Objects.key will work.

Comment: Direct use of ```.map()``` on objects isn't possible because ```.map()``` is an array method.  [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can map through nested data in an array of objects by using nested `map()` functions or by combining `map()` with other array methods like `flatMap()`

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    hobbies: ['Reading', 'Gardening']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Alice',
    hobbies: ['Painting', 'Cook`enter code here\'s']
  }
];
```

Comment: Actually,  I have tried this by using only the .map() but it still returns an error for me. Thank you for answering and giving me an insight

Comment: Your code doesn’t address the issue.

Comment: Further to the previous comment, the problem is that you cannot use `map` on a non-array object. I don't think any of this answer is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To display the languages, you need to iterate over the keys and values of the languages object. Here's how you can do it:

```js
  const country = {
    name: {},
    tld: [],
    subregion: "Western Europe",
    languages: {
       fra: "French",
       gsw: "Swiss German",
       ita: "Italian",
       roh: "Romansh"
    }
  }

  {Object.entries(country.languages).map(([code, language]) => (
      console.log(language)
  ))}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `map` function only works for object that has an array like `[{data1}, {data2}, {data3}]`

But in your case the `country.language` is not an array. Hence you need to specify like this :

```
country.language.data1
country.language.data2
country.language.data3
```

If you only use `country.language`, React will tell you.

You could make it an array:

```
const languageArray = countries.map(country => ([
          { 
            id: 1,
            name: country.language.fra
          },
          { 
            id: 2,
            name: country.language.gsw
          },
          { 
            id: 3,
            name: country.language.ita
          },
          ...
        ])
```

Now you can show the data using the `map` function.

```
               <div>
                   <ul>
                      {languageArray.map(language => (
                       <li key={language.id}>{language.name}</li>
                       )
                   </ul>
               </div>
```

Just make sure to use the `key` property since you're using `map` function

### Notes:

- The reason I added `id` because I want to render the `li` tag multiple time.
- `key` simply means that the tag is unique and that tag will contain each unique data. If you don't use the `key` attribute then the `map` function won't work. Also make sure the key value should be unique all the time. because you want each data to render right? If all of the data are unique, then no need to add **id** property at all.

Comment: **Do not** spam emojis in the posts you make here. They are unnecessary noise and objectively make content worse.

Comment: Please do not roll back the post anymore. What the above comment says is correct.